# Self referencing one-to-many relationship in EF Core 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I'm trying to achieve this desired schema:

Foo

```
FooId
1  
2 
3
```

FooMapping

```
ParentFooId | ChildFooId
1             2
1             3
```

I think I would need a model like this:

```cs
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Foo Parent { get; set; }
    public List<Foo> Children { get; set; }
}
```

And a configuration like:

```cs
builder.Entity<Foo>().HasMany(c => c.Children).WithOne(c => c.Parent);
```

Right now EF Core will take the above and create a schema like:

Foo

```
FooId | ParentId
```

I feel like a one-to-many mapping table would make more sense from a schema/querying perspective, no? How is that achieved with EF Core 5?

Comment: It's just a 1:n association, no junction table needed. It doesn't make sense schema- nor query-wise.

Answer (score -1):

> I feel like a one-to-many mapping table would make more sense from a schema/querying perspective, no?

Ok.  I feel like that's just an extra table.

> How is that achieved with EF Core 5?

By adding FooMapping as an Entity in your model.